# Flask generates the wrong template on the page

Tags: python, html, css, flask, flask-mail

I am writing a website on Flask, and I encountered a problem that when I send an email with a link to a password recovery page, the http address of which has a token that changes every time, the template that I connected is not generated at all. with completely wrong css styles.
Although the same template is connected in the same way to other pages and everything is fine, what is needed is generated

***Here is my view function to handle this page***

```
@app.route('/reset_password/<token>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reset_token(token):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index_page'))
    user = User.verify_reset_token(token)
    if user is None:
        flash('Неправильний,або застарілий токен', category='error')
        return redirect(url_for('reset_password'))
    form = ResetPasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hash_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data)
        user.password = hash_password
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('reset_password.html', title='Відновлення паролю', form=form,
                           css_link=css_file_reset_password_request_page)
```

***For comparison, here is a function that connects to the same css-style***

```
@app.route('/reset_password', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reset_password():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index_page'))
    form = RequestResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user is None:
            flash('Неправильний email', category='error')
        else:
            send_reset_email(user)
            flash('Повідомлення було надіслано на вашу електронну пошту,зайдіть туди,щоб отримати '
                  'інструкції', category='success')
    return render_template('reset_password_request.html', title='Відновлення паролю', form=form,
                           css_link=css_file_reset_password_request_page)
```

But as a result, these pages have a completely different look

***Here is the html template of this page(It is the same as reset_password_request from the previous function, only with some changes)***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
{{ super() }}
    {% for cat, msg in get_flashed_messages(True) %}
        <div class="flash {{cat}}">{{msg}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="container">
        <form class="box" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <h1 title="Будь ласка,придумайте новий надійний 
            пароль">Оновлення паролю</h1>
            <div class="group">
                <label>{{ form.password.label }}</label>
                {{ form.password }}
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <label>{{ form.double_password.label }}</label>
                {{ form.double_password }}
            </div>
            <div class="group">
                <center><button>Відновити</button></center>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

***THIS IS MY base.html FILE***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ css_link }}" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b8991598b2.js"></script>
    {% block title %}
        {% if title %}
            <title>{{ title }}</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>Сайт</title>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
        <header class="p-3 bg-dark text-white">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32" role="img" aria-label="Bootstrap"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
              <li><a href="/" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Features</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">About</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="search-box">
                <input class="search-txt" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
                <a class='search-btn' href="#">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="text-end">
                <a href='/register' class="btn btn-warning">Sign-up</a>
                <a href="/login" class="btn btn-warning">Login</a>
                <a href="/logout" class="btn btn-warning">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Pricing</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">FAQs</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

***And this is my connect to css_files in main.py***

```
css_file = 'static/css/main.css'
css_file_authorization = 'static/css/login_form.css'
css_file_reset_password_request_page = 'static/css/request_passsword.css'
```

But here is an example of a page that is generated after switching from email:
[image]

And here is the one that should have been generated, and is generated in the case of the second handler function

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to solve it

Comment: maybe the problem is how you include styles in base.html but we don't see it

Comment: No, all the templates on my site are copied from base.html, but such a template is generated only on this page

Comment: hmm, what are the logs/errors?

Comment: There are no errors, there are no logs, just this template is generated, which I don't even have in my files. But I have an opinion that it is possible that somehow this function reads the css template from my previous projects. Is this possible?

Comment: "this function reads the css template from my previous projects." No, i guess. And i still want to see `base.html` or just line where you load your css

Comment: I edited the post, now there is a ```base.html``` file and the connection to the css files in the project itself in the ```main.py``` file

Comment: all the links for your css must start with /

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, that helped, thank you very much, but I still don't understand why all files were connected to it without /, but this one was not

Comment: really don't know